# Create Google passkey for Web authentication

Tags: chrome-for-android, password, passkey

Webauthn passkey support is mainstream as of Chrome 108.

How do I generate a Google passkey using my android device?

Answer (score 2):

You'll be automatically prompted to create a passkey when visiting a Webauthn site or using an app that supports it.

---

If you want to kick-start the process:

- Open https://www.passkeys.io/
- Enter your email address
- Enter the OTP sent to your email address
- Tap "continue" when you see a prompt similar to this:
  [image]

To test:

- Logout
- Login again and notice you don't need to enter a password